# how to customise TextInputLayout in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

i want to customize my TextInputLayout that has TextInputEditText inside it to look exactly like an normal editText

here the current code

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:hint="@string/enter_email_or_username"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login_signup_linear_layout" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_input_field"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/email_edit_text"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:hint="@string/password" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

here is a screenshot
[image: screenshot]

so i have that password textInputLayout, and i want to make look exactly the same as that email editText